# How to maintain notes organized with org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a bunch of papers to read and taking notes. The problem is I don't have much time to spend looking for a way to organize my note taking system. For me emacs org-mode seems to be a quite powerfull solution, and pretty straightforward.

I encounter another problem, how can I keep my notes organized with a single file, in a way that I can rapidly access all the notes?

Comment: Emacs is a rewarding, but has a HUGE learning swerve -- i.e., not just a mere learning curve.  I've spent a year getting things the way I want, and am still not quite there yet.  If you really "don't have much time", then just make your notes in a flat text file without relying on a special major mode -- other than perhaps `text-mode`.

Comment: If you're already familiar with Emacs and just haven't tried `org-mode` yet, it shouldn't take you long to get started on that. Yes, Emacs is *infinitely customizable*, but `org-mode` is (among other things) a system for note taking, so as you would expect it provides a lot of useful functionality that you can use out of the box, without having to make a ton of modifications. On the other hand, if you have *never* used Emacs and have very little time on your hands for familiarizing yourself with it, you should probably go with @lawlist's suggestion or pick a different tool.

Comment: As for keeping notes organized within a single file (and accessing them rapidly), I suggest you start by learning about [Headlines](http://orgmode.org/manual/Headlines.html#Headlines), [Visibility Cycling](http://orgmode.org/manual/Visibility-cycling.html#Visibility-cycling), [Motion](http://orgmode.org/manual/Motion.html#Motion), and [Tags](http://orgmode.org/manual/Tags.html#Tags).

Comment: I already have some familiarity with Emacs, and also with org-mode. That's why I decided to use Emacs+org-mode. The question is, I want to organize my stuff in a compact way with easy access. I look for a straighfoward tutorial but didn't find any. So I thought that you guys already have did something like that.

Answer (score 5):

Since you're short time, you might do well to start with a simple system in which you can capture the notes you need to take, and worry later about organization. Consider the following:

```
* Title of a paper
** First section name
- A note
- Another note
** Second section name
- Yet another note
- A fourth note
- A fifth note

* Title of another paper
** First section name
- Yet more notes
** Second section name
- &c., &c.
```

Using paper titles as top-level section headings makes it easy to navigate among papers with isearch; `C-s Title of a paper RET` brings you to the section containing all your notes on that paper. From there, you can search for a section title, or just use TAB on headings to fold and unfold until you're looking at what you want.

Unless I've misunderstood your requirement, that should give you a pretty quick and straightforward way to dive in and start taking your notes, without losing navigability. That'll also give you an opportunity for some initial, shallow exploration of the problem domain; then, once you've gotten past the current glut of work and have time to think about how you *want* your note-taking system to work, you can explore the problem more deeply, using org-mode's quick outline rearrangement tools at need to turn the scheme you've got into the scheme you need.

Comment: That should do the trick by now. Could I put some links there to other `.org` files?

Comment: Sure! Org-mode's [linking facilities](http://orgmode.org/manual/Hyperlinks.html#Hyperlinks) are [remarkably extensive](http://orgmode.org/manual/External-links.html).

Comment: Works great, I exported as html file, all the links are completely working through all the files. Thanks